# Results of a post request in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I need to place the results of a (failed) post request (CSRF validation) in an IFrame for a Pentesting POC. Anyone got any ideas how I can pull that off?

Comment: failed post request in IFrame ?

Comment: You can target an iframe using `target` attribute in `<form>` but there is no control over what gets displayed using client client side code...that is all dependent on server side. Beyond that this question is too vague